# Apache Spark v/s Azure Synapse

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

I want to know the difference between Apache Spark and Azure Synapse?
What are they both in particular used for as separate services?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Synapse has a "managed" Spark, that is modified slightly from the open source version of Spark.  The Synapse implementation of Spark is intended to be easier and more accessible, but your mileage may vary.  Microsoft is also now offering a managed Spark inside of "Fabric" that will compete with the managed Spark inside of Synapse.  Personally I would avoid both of these, and host Spark workloads in HDInsight or Azure Databricks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a versus question.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-overview) for documentation on using Spark pools in Synapse.

You can think of Synapse as a cloud data warehousing product with a Spark add-on (e.g. for importing and analytics).  This is a slightly different view than Databricks which is Spark as the building block of all the offerings.

As to the inevitable "what is Spark?" follow on question - https://spark.apache.org/

Per comment - rough roles below, for anything else reading the documentation seems most sensible:

Synapse: data storage, governance, non Spark sql, tight Azure stack integration

Spark: distributed compute inc. sql

Comment: They both can run independent of one another as per my understanding. So what exactly is their individual roles? Apologies if this is sounding stupid.